# 3D эффект параллакса для фотографии (Depthy)

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, canvas, webgl

Когда-то копаясь в проектах WebGL находил [Depthy](http://depthy.me/#/sample/hut)

[Исходник](https://github.com/panrafal/depthy/tree/master/app) на github

Возникло желание попрактиковаться с реализацией такого эффекта, после чего сразу покопался в исходниках, где нашел основной [класс](https://github.com/panrafal/depthy/blob/f8bef19ce33590aec1c31fe294891432eaffd2f3/app/scripts/classes/DepthyViewer.js) для этого. Конечно разбираться в непрокомментированном коде нет охоты (там же и PIXI, о котором я слышу впервые), поэтому решил сразу спросить здесь, может растолкуете сам принцип и этапы, но и я по ходу изучения может смогу добавить информации.

В данный момент "под рукой" есть JS+Canvas, думаю для реализации этого будет достаточно

Пока мысль лишь о том, чтобы каждый пиксель изображения смещать по заданному оффсету(в данном случае это позиция курсора относительно центра) полагаясь на значение того же пикселя на карте глубины. Может тогда возникнут разрывы пикселей и эффект Nearest фильтрации, о чем я не могу пока что лишь предположить, но и это по ходу дела решится?!

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/03bsgcrf/1/) что получилось на данный момент чистым JS+Canvas

```
this.render=function(ctx,offsetX,offsetY) {


            for (var i = 0, l = output.width * output.height * 4; i < l; i += 4) {
                if(i<0 || i>l)continue;


                var depthK = (255-depthData[i/4])/5000;



                var offset=i+Math.round((Math.floor(offsetY*depthK)*output.width+Math.floor(offsetX*depthK)))*4;

                output.data[i] = mapData[offset];
                output.data[i + 1] = mapData[offset+1];
                output.data[i + 2] = mapData[offset+2];
            }



            ctx.putImageData(output,0,0);
        };
```

[И это](http://jsfiddle.net/e5y4c06z/1/) на WebGL. Быстрее и визуально приятнее. Весь код идентичен Hello World'овским, за исключением фрагментного шейдера, куда я передаю две текстуры, одна из которых накладывается на примитивы, а другая служит коэффициентом смещения для каждого пикселя по карте глубины

```
precision mediump float;
    uniform sampler2D map;
    uniform sampler2D depth;
    uniform vec2 offset;
    varying vec2 uv;


  void main(void) {

    vec2 texCoord = (uv+offset*(1.0-texture2D(depth,uv).z));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(map,texCoord).xyz, 1.0);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам [галерея фильтров pixi](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/15/indexAll.html). Поиграйтесь с displacement — это именно то, что вам нужно. А как захотите повторить — вот вам [код для этого](http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=filters&f=displacement-map.js&title=Displacement%20Map).

Я сам с этой библиотекой не сильно знаком, но полагаю, если вы начнете со странички "basics" и дочитаете до фильтров, все станет понятно.

Моя реализация: http://jsfiddle.net/ycj88zhs/2/

```
var image, depthMap, displacementMap;

image = load(
    'http://depthy.me/samples/hut-image.jpg',

function () {
    depthMap = load(
        'http://i.imgur.com/C4ZJY9m.jpg',

    function () {
        var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(
        image.canvas.width,
        image.canvas.height);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

        var stage = new PIXI.Container();
        stage.interactive = true;

        var container = new PIXI.Container();
        stage.addChild(container);

        var displacementSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(
            PIXI.Texture.fromCanvas(depthMap.canvas));
        displacementSprite.width = image.canvas.width;
        displacementSprite.height = image.canvas.height;

        stage.addChild(displacementSprite);

        var displacementFilter = new PIXI.filters.
            DisplacementFilter(displacementSprite);

        container.filters = [displacementFilter];

        displacementFilter.scale.x = 10;
        displacementFilter.scale.y = 10;

        var bg = new PIXI.Sprite(
            PIXI.Texture.fromCanvas(image.canvas));

        container.addChild(bg);

        stage.on('mousemove', onPointerMove)
             .on('touchmove', onPointerMove);

        renderer.render(stage);

        function onPointerMove(eventData) {
            var mouseOffsetX = eventData.data.global.x /
                        image.canvas.width;
            var mouseOffsetY = eventData.data.global.y /
                        image.canvas.height;

            displacementFilter.scale.x =
                mouseOffsetX * 20;
            displacementFilter.scale.y = 
                mouseOffsetY * 20;
            renderer.render(stage);
        }
    })
})

function load(path, callback) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.onload = function () {

        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        callback(canvas, ctx, img);
    };
    img.src = path;
    return {
        context: ctx,
        image: img,
        canvas: canvas
    };
}
```

Comment: Вариант с canvas по производительности более-менее на ПК справляется с небольшими фото, для начала сделал как тестовый, а вот реализовав на WebGL получилось весьма плавная анимация, но все же заметны артефакты при большом оффсте

Comment: Ну да, а там не нужно большой оффсет — ~10-20px хватит более чем.

Comment: Кстати, добавление размытия к карте высот сглаживает артефакты.

Comment: Да, спасибо, как раз час назад это обнаружил)

Comment: Если удастся добиться нормального результата, не поделитесь?

Comment: Конечно поделюсь) Пока "колдую" с обработкой карт глубины в редакторе, сама реализация уже есть на WebGL, позже на jsfiddle добавлю, то ли на этом и остановиться, или еще попробовать масштабировать части фото, которые отделены меньшей глубиной, то есть ближе всего, может это избавит от разводов

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25576/discussion-between-zelta-and-ni55an).